# Regex match all non-digits except decimal or comma at a specific position

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here are my numbers:

```
$1,000,000.00
100000000.00
100000
$1,000.00
2.000,00
10000,00
```

I would like to get:

```
1000000.00
100000000.00
100000
1000.00
2000,00
10000,00
```

Here is my regex:

```
[^\d(,.{3})]
```

I would like to remove all non-digits except a decimal or comma if it's in the 3rd position from the right. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character sets (or negative character sets) should *only* contain those characters that you want to match, or those you don't want to match - if you want to carry out additional tests (such as the character in question not being near the end of the line), do those tests *outside* of the character set.

Here, you can use the negative character set

```
[^\d\n,.]
```

to match characters that aren't digits, newlines, commas, or periods, and alternate that character set with

```
[,.](?!\d{2}$)
```

which will match periods and commas that aren't followed by two digits and the end of the line. In full:

```
[^\d\n,.]|[,.](?!\d{2}$)
```

and replace with the empty string. Output:

```
1000000.00
100000000.00
100000
1000.00
2000,00
10000,00
```

https://regex101.com/r/y0s1Bw/1